# What is the circumference of the legs of Usain bolt?

Tags: trivia, athletics

On [this site](http://celebrityinside.com/body-measurements/athlete/usain-bolt-height-weight-shoe-size-biceps-vital-statistics/) there are already a couple of measurements of Bolt but, unfortunately, not of his legs. What is the circumference of the legs of Usain bolt?